# Does a sliding vector act on each and every point of its line of action?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

According to the third paragraph of the introduction and the first paragraph under the title  "Sliding vectors in the plane" of this [article](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Efaris/vector5.pdf),

> Each bound vector $P, \textbf{u}$ determines a sliding vector $P ∧ \textbf{u}$.
> If $\textbf{u} = 0$, then the line $L$ is determined by
> $P$ and **u**. If $Q$ is another point on the same line $L$, then $P ∧ \textbf{u} = Q ∧ \textbf{u}$.
>
> ...
>
> Each non-zero sliding vector $P ∧ \textbf{u}$ represents a force
> applied to the point $P$.

Suppose $A, B, C, D, ...$ are also points on the line $L$ along with $P$ and $Q$. So,

$$P ∧ \textbf{u} = Q ∧ \textbf{u}=A ∧ \textbf{u} = B ∧ \textbf{u}=C ∧ \textbf{u}=\ ...\tag{1}$$

If $P ∧ \textbf{u}$ means that $\textbf{u}$ acts to $P$, and if $(1)$ is true, then doesnt it mean that the force $\textbf{u}$ acts to every single point on the line $L$?

Comment: How do you define "act to"?

Comment: @MishaLavrov If **u** is a force of 10N magnitude, then if **u** *acts at/to* the center of mass of a uniform cube of mass 10 kg object, then the object will start to accelerate at 1ms^-2 in the direction of **u**. This is how I define "act at/to". Am I correct, sir?

Comment: Presumably if you're telling me what you mean by a word, you can't be incorrect about that!

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yeah. Okay so, that's what I meant by act at/to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we're interpreting the sliding vector $P \wedge \mathbf u$ as applying a force at point $P$, we imagine that we have a rigid body, $P$ is a point on that rigid body, and $\mathbf u$ is a force pushing or pulling the rigid body at that point.

In this model, the force is not being applied anywhere other than $P$. The actual push or pull could be represented by the bound vector $(P, \mathbf u)$. The **effect** is represented by the sliding vector $P \wedge \mathbf u$.

So when we say that $P \wedge \mathbf u = Q \wedge \mathbf u$ (where $P,Q$ are points on a line parallel to $\mathbf u$), what we mean is that if $P,Q$ are two points of our rigid body, then applying a force of $\mathbf u$ at $P$ or at $Q$ will have the same effect.

For example, suppose your rigid body is a uniform cube with center of mass $P$, and you know that applying a force of $\mathbf u$ at $P$ will accelerate the cube by some amount in the direction of $\mathbf u$. In practice, you cannot reach into the cube and poke its center of mass. But you can poke the side of the cube, at point $Q$, and apply a force of $\mathbf u$ there. If the line through $P$ and $Q$ is parallel to $\mathbf u$, then poking the cube at point $Q$ will always have the same effect as poking the cube at its center of mass.

Actually, if $\mathbf u$ is the only force being applied to the cube - not even friction or anything like that is present - then lots more options become equivalent. Sliding vectors become relevant when we want to balance the forces. For example, if you and your friend are poking the cube equally hard from opposite sides, you are applying forces $\mathbf u$ and $-\mathbf u$ at points $Q$ and $R$.

1. If the line through $Q$ and $R$ is parallel to $\mathbf u$, then $$(Q \wedge \mathbf u) + (R \wedge -\mathbf u) = (R \wedge \mathbf u) + (R \wedge -\mathbf u) = R \wedge (\mathbf u - \mathbf u) = R\wedge \mathbf 0.$$ The cube doesn't go anywhere.
2. If the line through $Q$ and $R$ is not parallel to $\mathbf u$, then the sum of the sliding vectors is not a sliding vector. Your push and your friend's push together will cause the cube to rotate.

Explaining the first example in words: you are applying a force of $\mathbf u$ at $Q$, and your friend applies a force of $-\mathbf u$ at $R$. Because of the collinearity that says $Q \wedge \mathbf u = R \wedge \mathbf u$, your effect on the cube is the same as if you were applying force at $R$, too. And if you and your friend apply equal and opposite forces at the same point $R$, they negate each other.

Comment: Sir, I had a question about your answer: "The **effect** is represented by the sliding vector $P∧\textbf{u}$." Here, what do you mean by "effect"? If $P$ and $Q$ are two points on a rigid body and if **u** acts at $P$, and if the line through $P$ and $Q$ is parallel to **u**, then there's no difference between **u** acting at $P$ and **u** acting at $Q$; are you saying that this phenomenon/"effect" of sliding **u** is represented by $P\wedge \textbf{u}$? Is this what you mean by "effect" in the aforementioned sentence, sir?

Comment: I think yes. Put simply, the effect is what the rigid body will do when all these sliding-vector forces act on it. If you're pushing on a cube, and I decide to push back, the cube might do different things depending on where I push back. But if $P \wedge \mathbf u = Q \wedge \mathbf u$, then there is no difference between me pushing back with force $\mathbf u$ at point $P$, versus me doing the same at point $Q$.

Comment: "Put simply, the effect is what the rigid body will do when all these sliding-vector forces act on it."- So, do you mean the actual push or pull when you say "effect"? I'm nitpicking, but didn't you say, "The actual push or pull could be represented by the bound vector $(P,\textbf{u})$. The effect is represented by the sliding vector $P∧\textbf{u}$". From your phrasing here, there seems to be a difference between the "effect" represented by the sliding vector and the push-pull represented by the bound vector. I'm confused. Could you please explain it a bit more, sir?

Comment: If it's confusing, it's because I don't know the right words to explain it. Let me give another example: if you want to move a cube north, you could push against the south face (acting on the midpoint of that south face, $P$). Or, you could attach a rope to the north face, and pull (acting on the midpoint of the north face, $Q$). These are different bound vectors, but if you apply the same amount of force in the same direction, they will be the same sliding vector.

Comment: I'm scared to bother you more than I have; you used the word "effect" in the 2nd and the 3rd paragraph. Did you mean the same thing when you used the word "effect" in the 3rd paragraph as when you used the same word in the 2nd paragraph? In other words, do the two "effect"s mean the same thing in the 2nd and the 3rd paragraphs?

Comment: Yes, they mean the same thing.

Comment: Your answer was absolutely brilliant. Thank you.